# how to include mod_autorotate module in Apache config

Tags: apache, logrotate

It would be really helpful if some one could advice me how to include mod_autorotate in apache modules working in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the basic instructions at the authors website?

http://www.poptart.org/bin/view/Poptart/ModAutorotate

Comment: i'm following the same website. but im not able to compile the .c file using the apxs command mentioned because i've not installed apache extension tool. please suggest an alternative to install it in fedora

Comment: Install httpd-devel and compile the module you need, or phone a friend and have them compile it for you, or get on without this particular module and use the rotatelogs support in httpd.

Comment: thnx for ur comments,, if i cud hav phone afrnd i wudnt hav posted it here.. including ModAutorotate requires a lot of dependencies hence i found it not feasible to use that. hence i had to stick to the conventional logrotate module.